# css div and span display differently in browsers. How to unify?

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, divider

I have a CSS file that displays correctly in FF12, but it is different in Safari and Chrome.

IF IMAGES DON'T LOAD, VIEW A LIVE DEMO at http://beattrack.net/test.php

Here is what it should and does look like in FF:

[image: FF correct css]

And here is what happens in Safari and Chrome:

[image: Safari and Chrome difference]

Here is the relavant CSS and HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #topbar p.infotext {
        float: left;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        margin-left: 15px;
        color: #D8DFEA;
    }
    #topbar a.name, #topbar a.home {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-top: 4px;
        line-height: 32px;
        font-size: 13px;
        text-align: right;
        color: #D8DFEA;
        padding-left: 12px;
        float: right;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-right: 0px;
    }
    .divider {
        margin-top: 7px;
        line-height: 19px;
        border-right: 1px solid #5CCD3E;        
        float: right;
    }
</style>

<html>
  <div id="topbar">
    <a class="home" href="#">Home &nbsp; <span class="divider">&nbsp;</span></a>
    <a class="name" href="#"><?php echo $first_name . " " . $last_name . " &nbsp; ";?>
    <span class="divider">&nbsp;</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: images didn't load for some reason. I'll try changing them. Basically, the dividers are far too low in Safari and Chrome.

Comment: They load fine for me. Post a link to the webpage or a live demo of a page demonstrating the problem.

Comment: http://beattrack.net/test.php live demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'd recommend using an image rather than tacking on an extra `.divider` class, here is how I would modify your markup: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/z9Esg/

HTML:

```
<div id="topbar">
    <a href="#">
        <strong>Home</strong><span></span>
    </a><a href="#">
        <strong>Adam Wexler</strong><span></span>
    </a>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#topbar { text-align: right; }
#topbar a { 
    padding: 0 0 0 12px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;​ }
#topbar strong, #topbar span { 
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
#topbar strong { font-weight: normal; }
#topbar a:hover strong { text-decoration: underline; }
#topbar span { 
    background-color: #5CCD3E;
    height: 19px;
    width: 1px;
    margin: 0 0 0 12px; }​
```

Comment: Sure, let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a width should get it to work.

```
#topbar a.home, #topbar a.name {width : 70px;}
```

Comment: that worked great! The only thing is that the "name" part is really a variable and I need the width to be adjustable with the length of the name so it looks right on hover (I changed it up top).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.divider {
    position:relative;
    top: 7px;
    line-height: 19px;
    border-right: 1px solid #5CCD3E;        
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a problem with the HTML.

When I removed the "&nbsp" from after the text, it worked great for me.

```
  <div id="topbar">
    <a class="home" href="#">Home
    <span class="divider">&nbsp;</span></a>
    <a class="name" href="#">
    <?php
    echo $full_name." ".$tel;
    ?>
    <span class="divider">&nbsp;</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

I'd love any feedback as to WHY that worked...

Comment: It's because you are using `float` inside of an `inline` element. You might want to look for solutions that don't require you to use `float` (such as using `inline` elements, or `background-image`). See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925475/css-div-and-span-display-differently-in-browsers-how-to-unify/10941116#10941116) for one such alternative.